# use variable from php as an alert for javascript

Tags: php, javascript, variables, alert

how can i use the variable from my php-sql to become the message for my javascript alert?

heres my code

```
<?php

    $select = "SELECT * FROM post";
    $result = mysql_query($select) or die("couldn't select table");


    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo"<input type='button' class=term onclick='return terms()' value=Terms >";

        echo"<input type='hidden' value='$rows[terms]' id='term' name='term'>";
    }
?>  

<script language="JavaScript">
    function terms() 
    {
        var readers = document.getElementById("term"); 
        alert(readers.value);
    }
</script>
```

It works, the alert message displays. But I got the problem on displaying the right message for specific fetch of row. All got the same message (message from the first row).

I tried to use getElementByName but the alert doesn't pop-up,
so i dont have to try making the input name="term[]" --------(into its array form)

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be find if you change this line of script

```
 echo"<input type='button' class=term onclick='terms()' value=Terms >";
```

onclick='terms()' here, instead of onclick='return terms()'

EDIT:

```
<?php   echo"<input type='button' class=term onclick='terms(this)' data-result ='". $rows['terms'] ."' value=Terms >"; ?>
      /* Remove the hidden field */
<script language="JavaScript">
    function terms(e) 
    {
        var readers = e.getAttribute('data-result'); 
        alert(readers);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i changed, but alert doesn't showed when i used getElementByName

Comment: sorry i don't know what you mean console is... newbie here

Comment: by the way @JustinJohn
is data-result a reserve word or just a variable?
I googled it and there is no such result. :)

Comment: @ivory-santos: It's an attribute name. You can use any other word except the reserve words like name, class etc for that attribute. The `data-result` is data attribute. You can check about data attributes. You should learn basics of html elements.

Answer (score 1):

Change your second echo statement inside the while loop to:

```
echo"<input type='hidden' value='". $rows['terms'] ."' id='term' name='term'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the following:

```
<?php
  function alert($text){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$text.'")</script>';
  }

  alert("test");
?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i dont get it, is "test" diff from "$text" ?

Comment: $text is a variable, "test" is the value that you set $text to.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value or "term" in your HTML code after each iteration of While-loop. This way it will only get the last value

Answer (score 0):

All of your `input` elements have the same `id`. If you want to distinguish them, give them different identifiers. And pass the identifier to the `terms` function.

Answer (score 0):

You must give different id for each element. I think simple way to do that is by using auto increment for the id.